# When trying to record backup files to my BD-R burner, I get "media is not recognized as recordable DVD" on two different drives that worked before

Tags: linux, optical-drive, optical-media

My Fedora 36 based server (fully updater) has a SATA BD-R drive and a USB BD-R drive. I am trying to spool some backup files out from HDD to BD-R (really Verbatim M-Disc 100GB BDXL media) using [`growisofs`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/growisofs). The drives are:

- **SATA drive**: LG HL-DT-ST BD-RE WH16NS40
- **USB drive**: Pioneer BDR-XDO5S

Both drives give me this error:

> “media is not recognized as recordable DVD.”

Both drives have worked before. In the past, rebooting the system has helped.

Sometimes unplugging the USB drive and reconnecting it have worked, but not today.

Any hints for troubleshooting? Any hints for how to reset the SATA drive short of power cycling the server?

---

It was suggested that I retrieve some information using `crdecord -prcap`:

```
cdrskin: NOTE : ignoring unimplemented option : '-prcap'
cdrskin: NOTE : option is waiting for a volunteer to implement it.

[root@shadow backup3]# cdrecord -minfo dev=/dev/sr1
cdrskin 1.5.4 : limited cdrecord compatibility wrapper for libburn
cdrskin: NOTE : greying out all drives besides given dev='/dev/sr1'
cdrskin: scanning for devices ...
cdrskin: ... scanning for devices done

Note: This is not cdrecord by Joerg Schilling. Do not bother him.
      See cdrskin start message on stdout. See --help. See -version.

cdrskin: pseudo-atip on drive 0
cdrskin: SORRY : Asynchronous SCSI error on waiting after START UNIT (+ LOAD): [2 30 00] Drive not ready. Incompatible medium installed.
cdrskin: FATAL : unable to open drive 0
```

Comment: Odd. Have you checked the output of `cdrecord -prcap`?

Comment: Yes. It took me a bit of time to find it, since it does not come with Fedora, but I installed it with crskin.
I edited the question to show the results. I am no wiser.